# Indicar si la cantidad de numeros ingresados es par o impar

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de la facultad y me pide desarrollar un programa que solicite al usuario una cantidad de numeros e indicar si esta cantidad es par o impar. La lectura de datos va a finalizar cuando el usuario ingrese -1. Y la consigna me dice que lo haga sin usar contadores.
Tampoco usar listas. Dijo el profesor que lo tratemos de resolver desde la logica, pero no puedo hacerlo.
Aca dejo mi codigo hasta ahora en Python:

```
# Ingresar un conjunto de numeros para informar si la cantidad ingresada es par o impar.
# Finalizar la lectura de datos ingresando -1

print('Ingrese un conjunto de numeros.')
print('Ingrese -1 para finalizar la lectura de datos. A continuacion se indicara si la cantidad ingresada es par o impar.')

inicio = 0
suma = 0

while inicio != -1:
    numero = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))
    suma += numero
    if (suma % 2) == 0:
        if numero == -1:
            print('La cantidad ingresada es impar.')
    else:
        if numero == -1:
            print('La cantidad ingresada es par.')
```

Comment: Y que es lo que obtienes? Cual es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Que me indique si la cantidad de numeros ingresada por el usuario es par o impar.

Comment: Si es solo la cantidad de números, entonces no es necesario calcular su suma, ¿o si?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es solo para verificar si la cantidad de datos introducidos es par o impar, puedes usar el concepto de "switch", on/off

```
par = False
inicio = 0

while inicio != -1:
    inicio = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))
    par = not par # Por cada iteración cambiará True, False, True, ...

print('La cantidad ingresada es', 'par' if (par) else 'impar')
```

[*] Debido a que `-1`, es la condición de salida y que también cambia el valor de la variable `par`, entonces para corregirlo `par` empieza por `False`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho. :)

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta y solucionó el problema, puedes considerar marcarla como aceptada clicando el tick a la izquierda. Esto ayudará a futuros usuarios a saber que respuesta soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno una vez echo unas simplificación a tu codigo y arreglado cuando determinas si un numero es par o no, queda asi:

```
print('Ingrese un conjunto de numeros.')
print('Ingrese -1 para finalizar la lectura de datos. A continuacion se indicara si la cantidad ingresada es par o impar.')

inicio = 0
suma = 0

while inicio != -1:
    numero = int(input('Ingrese un numero: '))
   #se verifica si no es-1 ya que sino se le resta a la suma 
    if numero == -1:              
         if (suma %) 2 == 0:
              print('La cantidad ingresada es par.',suma)
              suma = 0 #regresamos la suma a 0
         else:
              print('La cantidad ingresada es impar.',suma)
              suma = 0
    else:
         suma += numero
```

Si no quieres formatear la suma solo omite `suma = 0`